# C++ select first not null element

Tags: c++, naming, std

**[question update according to updated requirements]**
I've implemented following function which should return either first not null element or throw an exception.
Also could you invent more classic and shorter name like 'max', 'min', 'pair'?

```
template <typename T>
T select_first_not_empty( const T& a, const T&b )
{
    static T null = T();

    if ( a == null && b == null )
        throw std::runtime_error( "null" );

    return
        a != null ? a : b;
}

int main()
{
    const int a1 = 2;
    const int b1 = 0;

    const int* a2 = 0;
    const int* b2 = new int(5);

    const std::string a3 = "";
    const std::string b3 = "";

    std::cout << select_first_not_empty( a1, b1 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << select_first_not_empty( a2, b2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << select_first_not_empty( a3, b3 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try do next

```
template < typename T >
T get_valuable( const T& firstValue, 
                const T& alternateValue, 
                const T& zerroValue = T() )
{
    return firstValue != zerroValue ? firstValue : alternateValue;
}

// usage
char *str = "Something"; // sometimes can be NULL
std::string str2 ( get_valuable( str,  "" ) );

// your function
template <typename T>
T select_first_not_empty( const T& a, 
                          const T& b, 
                          const T& zerroValue = T() )
{
    const T result = get_valuable( a, b, zerroValue );
    if ( result == zerroValue )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error( "null" );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I guess you wanted do something other in this sample code. 
But you've mixed some "zero value" and "default value"

Comment: Where is the exception thorw?

Comment: Sorry for that. I like the idea of two functions and zeroValue. The last thing to come up with is a good enough name to be the util function.

Comment: The "zerovcalue" would possibly confusing if you named the function coalesce (as in SQL). In SQL, the function accepts 2 or more arguments. coalesce(a,b,c)=coalesce(a,coalesce(b,c)).

Answer (score 3):

<strike>If the ctor for T does anything significant, it appears like you're doing it three times every time through "select_first_not_empty".</strike>

Oracle calls something similar "COALESCE", if you're looking for a better name.

I'm not sure what the point is, though.  If I really wanted to know whether something was set or not, I'd use nullable pointers rather than references.  "NULL" is a far better indicator of the intent to not have the variable set than to use an in-band value like 0 or "".

Answer (score 2):

C# has a similarly functioning built-in operator `??`, which I believe is called coalesce.

Perl's `||` (short-circuit logical OR) operator also has similar functionality: instead of return 0 or 1, it returns the value of the first argument evaluating to true:

```
0 || 7
```

returns 7, not 1 or `true` as a C\C++ or C# programmer would expect.

The closest thing to this that C++ has built in is the find_if algorithm:

```
vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(0);
vec.push_back(0);
vec.push_back(7);

vector<int>::iterator first_non_0 = 
    find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), bind2nd(not_equal_to<int>(), 0));
```

Comment: I realize, I was just giving you pointers to try and think of a name you'd like.  There is no built-in C++ version of this, and your version looks like it works.